# Images not updating properly in Database

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have created dynamic add / remove file field to insert image in database. But somehow it is not working properly. Following is my code...

```
$member_image_names = array_map( 'sanitize_file_name', $_FILES['member_image']['name'] );
foreach ( $member_image_names as $member_image_name ) {

    if ( empty( $member_image_name ) ) {

        global $wpdb;
        $project_id = $_SESSION['project_id'];
        $project_member_details = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT project_members FROM wpxa_orocox_project_members WHERE project_id = %d", $project_id ) );
        $project_member_detail = json_decode( $project_member_details, true );
        $member_image_newname = $project_member_detail['member_image'];

    } else {

        $member_image_ext = strtolower( end( explode( '.', $member_image_name ) ) );
        $member_image_newname[] = get_current_user_id() . $_SESSION['project_id'] . "_" . time() . "_" . mt_rand() . "." . $member_image_ext;

    }

$member_details->member_image = $member_image_newname;

$member_details_encode = wp_json_encode( $member_details );

global $wpdb;

$members_result_update = $wpdb->update( 'wpxa_project_members',

  array( 'project_members' => $member_details_encode ),

  array( 'project_id' => $_SESSION['project_id'] ),

  array( '%s' ),

  array( '%d' )

);

if ( ! empty( $members_result_update ) ) {

$member_details_decode = json_decode($member_details_encode, true);
$count_member_decode = count( $member_details_decode['member_image'] );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count_member_decode; $i++ ) {
 $m_image_name = $member_details_decode['member_image'][$i]; 

$profile_image_folder = "profile-images/";
$profile_image_path = trim( $profile_image_folder . basename( $m_image_name ) );
$profile_image_temp = $_FILES['member_image']['tmp_name'][$i];
$profile_image_ext = strtolower( end( explode( '.', $m_image_name ) ) );

if ( $profile_image_ext == "jpg" || $profile_image_ext == "png" || $profile_image_ext == "jpeg" || $profile_image_ext == "gif" ) {

move_uploaded_file( $profile_image_temp, $profile_image_path );

}

}

}

}
```

Every thing works well but when I select a new image in first field and submit the value to the database, it removes all other images of other fields from database...

And if I select image for other fields and submit the value to database it then creates new field with that value...

In simple terms, When I want to update any particular file field in the dynamic add / remove file field then that particular field should only be get updated and other fields should remain intact.

Pl Help...

Comment: try passing "where" condition along with the update query

Comment: @charankumar can u plz elaborate... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and i did it :(Example)

`if ( empty( $options['index1_cardimg'] ) ) {$options['index1_cardimg'] = get_myoption_value('index1_cardimg');}`

without this check (if (empty){}) all other fields will be reset .

just you need to fill them by last data (if they dont send) .

with a code like this:

```
if ( empty( $members_result_update ) ) {
// fill Other options with last value 
}
```